# Pointwise and uniform convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2},\ x>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am given the exercise: Check the pointwise and uniform convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2},\ x>0$.

It is like that: $$n^2x^2 \leq 1+n^2x^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n^2x^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2} $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}< +\infty$$

Do we conclude from this that $\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$ converges pointwise to a function $s(x)$ ?

Also,how can I check if the series converges pointwise to a function?

Comment: For uniform convergence, you can check, by setting $x=1/n$, that the terms of the series do not converge uniformly to $0$. Thus, the convergence is not uniform on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Could you explain me why we can take a specific $x$ and show that the limit of this does not converge to $0$,in order to show that the convergence is not uniform?

Comment: A series converges uniformly if and only if it is uniformly Cauchy. See the second paragraph [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136909/show-uniform-convergence-of-function-series/136910#136910). This, in particular, implies that the terms, $f_n$, of a uniformly convergent series, $\sum f_n$,  must converge to $0$ uniformly. For your series, the terms $f_n(x)={1\over 1+n^2x^2}$ do not converge to $0$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, since for each $n$, $f_n(1/n)=1/2$...

Comment: Taking specific values of $x$ suffices here: for $\epsilon=1/2$, there is no $N$ so that $|f_n(x)-0|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and all $x>0$. By definition, then, $(f_n)$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're correct and by this way you proved the pointwise convergence of the series on $(0,+\infty)$. Now since
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$$
doesn't exist then the convergence isn't uniform on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Moreover, let $a>0$ then
$$\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}\le\frac1{a^2n^2},\quad\forall x\ge a$$
and the series $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent then the given series is uniformly convergent on every interval $[a,+\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: I understand!!!Thank you!!!
$$$$
At a solution,I found it is done like that:
$$s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}, s_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$$
and then they find the difference $|s(x)-s_k(x)|$,and its supremum to prove that it does not converge to $0$.
Could you explain me why we can do it like that? I haven't understood it...

Comment: This is the definition of the uniform convergence of the series: the series $s(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}u_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on the interval $I$ if
$$\sup_{x\in I}|s(x)-s_k(x)|=\sup_{x\in I}\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty u_n(x)\right|\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$$

Comment: Ok,so can I use this relation:
$$\sup_{x>0} |\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}| \geq \sup_{x>0} \frac{1}{1+(k+1)^2x^2}=1$$
?

Comment: Yes you can use this relation: notice  that by taking $x=\frac1n$ as suggested by David Mitra we see that the $\sup=\infty$ so we haven't the uniform convergence.

Comment: Ok,so I can take $x=\frac{1}{n}$ or $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$,to show that the convergence is not uniform,right?

Comment: Yes right and the former we used the definition and the last we used a propriety of the limit for the uniform convergence and both give the same result.

Comment: Nice,thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You were busy (answering questions) yesterday! ;-)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I am looking again at the execise..why from the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$ does not exist,do we conclude that the convergence is not uniform?

Comment: By the definition of the uniform convergence:
$\sup_{x>0}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}\right|=\sup_{x\ge0}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}\right|\\\ge\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+k^2\times0^2}\right|=\infty$
so the divergence isn't uniform.@evinda