# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {x^2+n}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {x^2+n}{n^2}$    is uniformly
>   convergent on arbitrary interval.

I wanted to use M test for arbitrary [a,b]  $|(-1)^n\frac {x^2+n}{n^2}|\le|(\frac{b^2+n}{n^2})|\le (\frac{b^2+n^2}{n^2})|=M_n$

it seems $\sum M_n=b^2\sum\frac{1}{n^2}+1=\frac {b^2\pi^2}{6}+1$ is it correct?

Comment: This is unfortunately incorrect; a $1$ sneaked outside your series.

Comment: The convergence is not uniform on an unbounded interval (the terms do not converge uniformly to zero on an unbounded interval).

Comment: Note for such an "alternating series", the convergence is uniform if and only if the terms, in absolute value, are pointwise decreasing and converge uniformly to zero. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136909/show-uniform-convergence-of-function-series).

Comment: By the way, the $M$-test won't help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirichlet's test shows that the series is uniformly convergent on a bounded interval. The term $(-1)^n$ has bounded partial sums and the term $(n+x^2)/n^2$ converges monotonically and uniformly to $0$ for $x \in [a,b]$.