# Question related to convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {x^2+n} {n^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

We have the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {x^2+n} {n^2}$. Which test ensure that the series convergence for all real value of $x$ and how can we confirm that this series does not converge absolutely for any real vale of $x$.

MY TRY:I just used ratio test but I did not get any clue for the purpose.Thank you

Comment: Well the series is alternating, what test is named after such a series?

Comment: You mean Leibniz's test?

Comment: You can find several questions about this series, for example, this one: [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ converges uniformly, but not absolutely](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509086). Several similar questions seem to be among the first hits if you try [searching in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20(-1)%5En%5Cfrac%20%7Bx%5E2%2Bn%7D%20%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute convergence, since Nameless has taken care of standard convergence, note that $|(-1)^n\frac{x^2 + n}{n^2}| = \frac{x^2}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}$. Does this sound any alarms for you? It should!

Comment: are you talking about term test or ratio test?@David

Comment: I'm talking about neither. $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series, one the most famous series in math. What do you know about the convergence of this series?

Comment: This series is divergent.

Comment: Yep! So now what can you conclude?

Comment: That the given series does not converge absolutely..right?

Comment: That's right, good job.

Comment: $\sum\frac{1}{n}\leq\sum\frac{x^2}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}$.is this ok to conclude the above?@david

Comment: Yes, since each $\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ term is nonnegative.

Comment: No problem, Subrat!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether

(1) $\lim_n \frac{x^2 + n}{n^2} = 0$

(2)$ \left ( \frac{x^2 + n}{n^2} \right )_{n \geq 1}$ is a decreasing sequence.

Use [this test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

I'll give you some hints

(1) Just treat $x^2$ as a constant.

(2) Plot the function and once again fix $x^2$

> yes it converges