# Determine in each function series if it converges uniformly, pointwise or diverges

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

[image]

where domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to use the root test and I got $\sin x$, but it its defined  between $1$ and $-1$, so by the test does it mean it does not converge?

[image]

where domain is $[-1,3]$

In this one I dont have a clue.

Comment: Do you know the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: Yes, but isnt it a problem with the power of n in the sin function?

Comment: Why would there be? $|\sin x|\leq 1,$ so the same is true for the $n$th power.

Comment: yeah then its very simple with M test, got you

Comment: For the other part, check out something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136909/show-uniform-convergence-of-function-series

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second series does not converge uniformly on the line. If it does then the n-th term must tend to zero uniformly and this implies $|x^{2}|/n$ is less than $1$ for all $x$ as long as $n$ is large enough. Can see that this is false?

Comment: do you mean proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, prove it by contradiction.

Comment: but why you ignored (-1)^n? because its not significant?

Comment: A sequence $c_n$ tends to $0$ iff  $|c_n|$ tends to $0$ iff $(-1)^{n}c_n$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I did the root test on that and got -1, which implies it converges to zero. I dont understand why its not uniformly. because its limited in the domain?